# Example of Markov chain

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

I am struggling to solve this problem. I have no idea about how to tackle it. Please pardon me for not showing what I can I do. Thank you.

Let $X= \{X_n; n= 0, 1 \ldots\}$ be a Markov chain with state space $J$ and transition matrix $P.$ Fix a state $i$ and suppose $p(i,i)>0$. Let $$T=\text{inf} \{n\geq 1; X_n \neq i \}$$
Assume that the Markov chain starts in state $i$.

For $j \neq i$ and $n = 1,2, \ldots,$ find $$P_i\{X_T = j, T= n\}$$ and for $j \neq i$ find $$P_i \{X_T = j \}$$

Answer (score 0):

Conditioned on $\{X_0=i\}$, the event $\{X_T=j,T=n\}$ corresponds to $n-1$ transitions from $i$ to $i$ followed by one transition from $i$ to $j$. By the law of total probability, we have
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(X_T=j\mid X_0=i) &= \mathbb P\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \{X_T=j,T=n\mid X_0=i\}\right)\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb P(X_T=j,T=n\mid X_0=i).
\end{align}
Can you finish it from there?

Comment: Not really but I appreciate your effort. I even find it difficult grasping the meaning of the question. I would appreciate it if you could throw more light on the meaning and significance of the question in detailed.

Comment: could you have a look at what I've got here? $P_i(X_j, T=n) = P(X_T = j | T = n) P(T = n)$ and $P_i(X_T=j) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P(X_T = j | T = n) P(T = n)$

Comment: Those expressions don't have $i$ on the right-hand side, which doesn't make sense...